# C# MVC ASP.NET CRUD Creating Data Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a `Customer` model and 3 files: `Customer.cs`, `CustomerDto.cs`, and `ICustomer.cs`.

In my customer.cs, I have:

```
internal class Customer : ICustomer
{
    private CustomerDto _record;

    public Customer(CustomerDto record = null)
    {
        if (record == null) 
        {
            record = new CustomerDto(); 
        }

        _record = record;
    }

    public long Id
    {
        get { return _record.Id; }
        set { _record.Id = value; }
    }

    // plus some other values

    public IAddress Address 
    {
        get { return _record.Address; }
        set { _record.Address = value; }
    }
}
```

In my `customerDTO.cs` file:

```
public class CustomerDto : ICustomerRecord
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    // plus some other values ...
    public IAddress Address { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, my `ICustomer.cs` file is:

```
public interface ICustomerRecord
{
    long Id { get; set; }
    // some other values
    IAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public interface ICustomer : ICustomerRecord
{
    bool Save();
    bool Delete();
}

public interface IAddress 
{
    string Street { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; }
    string State { get; set; }
    string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to create an `Address` data object within my customer, and my address object should have a function that formats my address like so:

```
    public string AddressFormatter(IAddress Address)
    {
        return Address.Street + "\n" + Address.City + ", " + Address.State + " " + Address.Zip; 
    }
```

But I am confused in terms of which files to define my address and my `addressFormatter` in, given my current data model setup with customers. Any pointer and help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could put the formatter in a new helper class called `StringHelper` or `AddressHelper` or adding a property in your `class Address : IAddress` that returns a formatted address. If you decide to create a helper class, the same method can be used for any class that implements IAddress.

Comment: Address class should be on separate file, but I don't think you need an AddressFormatter, you can override ToString() method of Address class instead.

Comment: @derloopkat can you post an example of how it would look like if I were to implement a full /Address Folder aside from /Customer with the street, city, state, zip? Im confused int terms of the difference between their DTOS, the actual models, and the interfaces...

Comment: @FLICKER I am a little confused, how does that work between the DTO, Interface and actual customers data class